# 2D array as pointer to char array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am playing with some code in C and also I am trying to understand relationship between pointers and arrays. As you probably know, when I want to make array it could be done like this:

```
char * arr = "abc";
```

or

```
char arr[] = {'a','b', 'c'};
```

But when I want to do 2D array. It must be done like this

```
char arr[3][10];
```

Why declaration like this crashes when I try to load string to that.

```
char * names[3];

for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
    printf("Enter name %d: ", i+1 );
    scanf("%s", names[i]);
}
// print names
printf("\nEntered names are: \n");
for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
    printf("%s\n", names[i] );
}
```

It should be 2D array right? Because array is basically pointer. 
Could you please explain that?
Thanks.

Comment: The crash for `char *names[3];` really depends on how you use it. What are you doing with this array? What is the problem this array is supposed to solve?

Comment: Detail: "when I want to make array it could be done like this: `char arr * = "abc";`".  -->  Here `arr` is a pointer, not an array,  _String literal_ `"abc"` is an array.

Comment: "Because array is basically pointer" --> Not so.  An array is like an apartment building with many units.  A pointer is like the address of the unit.  I can easily carry the address written on paper in my pocket.  I can not carry the unit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char * names[3];
```

Is not a 2D array, it's an array of three pointers to `char`, if you want to store `char arrays` in it you must allocate memory to each individual pointer, something like:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    names[i] = malloc(/*length your array of chars*/);
}
```

You can then store `char arrays`, using you example:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    printf("Enter name %ld: ", i + 1 );
    scanf("%29s", names[i]); //for a malloc size of 30
}
```

Note that you must be careful with `scanf`, if the inputed string is longer then the memory allocated to store it you will have stack smashing, i.e. for `names[i]` with size of `30`, you should use `%29s` specifier, instead of `%s`. Though this approach is not whitout its issues, namely possible characters left in `stdin` buffer, it's definitely safer.

Alternatively you can assign them string literals (in this case it's best to declare the array as `const`, otherwise if you try to edit one or more characters it'll result in a segfault):

```
const char* names[3];

for(size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    names[i] = "My string literal";
}
```

You can also make them point to existing `char arrays`:

```
char arr[3][10];
char* names[3];

for(size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    names[i] = arr[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
char * names_1[3];
```

It's not a pointer. It's an array of pointers.

```
char names_2[3][10]={"one", "two", "three"};
char (*p_names_2)[10]=names_2;
```

Now it's a pointer to your 2D-Array. Just define a function and try to use it with your "pointers" as parameters.

```
void print_names(char names[][10], const int row){
    for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
      puts(names[i]);
}
```

Now call it with:

```
print_names(names_2, 3); 
print_names(p_names_2, 3);
print_names(names_1, 3); //WRONG
```

And you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

`char* names[3]` is not strictly a 2D array (they don't exist in C or C++); it's an array of arrays. So each element of names contains simply a `char*`, which has not been initialised.

Note also that a c-style string is a *null-terminated* array of chars, so your original `arr` is not a c-style string. To make it a c-style string you would need:

```
char arr[] = {'a','b','c',0};
```

making it an array of length 4, not 3.

Missing off the null-terminator will mean that most functions will run off the end of the allocated memory, because they won't know when the string stops.

Answer (score 1):

pointer is a type of variable, which can only contain an address of another variable. It can't contain any data. You can't store data into a pointer.Pointers should point at memory location.

So to use a pointer in the right way ,it must always point at a valid memory location in stack or memory dynamically allocated in heap.

this `char * names[3]` is an array of pointers ,so you need to reserve memory for it and then initialize it.You need to use some thing like this:

```
char *name[3];
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
name[i]=malloc(strlen(string)+1);
}
```

also you should allocate memory for `char *arr` too.

`char *arr=malloc(strlen(data)+1)`

then initialized it.